modifing the word vectors for Cosine Similarity based on associated words
I am trying to use cosine similarity for summing a group of words that will output a tag. think of "knight" + "queen" + "king" = "chess"
however due to my tag definitions, I end up with a lot of overlap using this method.
"knight" + "queen" + "king" = "chess"
"queen" + "king" = "cards"
I have read up on cosine similarity in hopes of finding an equation that can include negative word associations but so far my sources have been dry.
is it possible to include negative word associations in cosine similarity calculations and is there a good resource I can use to read up on it?
